# Swiper using cdn link is not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I want to add Swiper Slider on my website. I have added Swiper CDN to my html. But it is not working. I don't know what is wrong with my code. I have copy pasted the same code which Swiper has on it's website. But still it does not slide. Can anyone help me what is that I am missing.

From here I copy pasted the code.
https://swiperjs.com/get-started#use-swiper-from-cdn

Below is the screenshot for your reference. When I click arrow buttons slide does not move.
[image: screenshot for reference]

HTML CODE -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <title> </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="dvHeader">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Press Media</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Enquiry</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="dvSlider">
        <!-- Slider main container -->
        <div class="swiper">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slides -->
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                ...
            </div>
            <!-- If we need pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

            <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

            <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
            <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            // Optional parameters
            direction: 'vertical',
            loop: true,

            // If we need pagination
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
            },

            // Navigation arrows
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },

            // And if we need scrollbar
            scrollbar: {
                el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            },
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the answer.

I shifted this script above like this and added css, check below code and css. This worked.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const swiper = new Swiper('.dvSlider .swiper', {
            // Optional parameters
            // direction: 'vertical',
            // loop: true,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            loop: true,

            // If we need pagination
            pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination",
                clickable: true,
            },

            // Navigation arrows
            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
            },

            // And if we need scrollbar
            scrollbar: {
                el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            },
        });
    </script>
```

CSS -

```
.dvSlider .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try, changed the javascript code

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-js", {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <title> </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="dvHeader">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Press Media</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Enquiry</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="dvSlider">
        <!-- Slider main container -->
        <div class="swiper swiper-js">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slides -->
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
                ...
            </div>
            <!-- If we need pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

            <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

            <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
            <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @dita but I want it just above the closing body tag which is the place which is recommended to keep all the scripts.

Comment: it's can also works actually, haha, I think the problem is with the `loop` or `direction` script code

Answer (score 0):

You write shipper script code before the library load this cause it's a js error in console I fixed your code and paste you can directly use the code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <title> </title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="dvHeader">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Press Media</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Enquiry</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="dvSlider">
        <!-- Slider main container -->
        <div class="swiper">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slides -->
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1002" alt=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1002" alt=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1002" alt=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1002" alt=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1002" alt=""> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- If we need pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

            <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

            <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
            <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
         const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            // Optional parameters
           
            // If we need pagination
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
            },

            // Navigation arrows
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },

            // And if we need scrollbar
            scrollbar: {
                el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            },
        });

        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```